# Multiple table query with count error

Tags: sql, oracle

Whenever I add a count to the following select statement, it causes it to give me an error, and I'm not sure why:

```
select "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Vehicles"."Model", "Vehicles"."Color",
"Vehicles"."LicensePlate", COUNT("WorkOrderPart"."WorkPartID") AS "Parts"
FROM "WorkOrder", "Vehicles", "WorkOrderPart"
WHERE "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" AND
"WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID" = "WorkOrderPart"."WorkOrderID";
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error:

```
select "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Vehicles"."Model", "Vehicles"."Color",
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

What can I do about this? I am running the SQL command line with an Oracle database.

Answer (score 6):

When you have a `count` (or other aggregate function), you need to `group by` the non aggregated items

```
select 
     "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", 
     "Vehicles"."Model", 
     "Vehicles"."Color",
     "Vehicles"."LicensePlate", 
     COUNT("WorkOrderPart"."WorkPartID") AS "Parts"
FROM "WorkOrder", "Vehicles", "WorkOrderPart"
WHERE "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" 
AND "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID" = "WorkOrderPart"."WorkOrderID"
group by  "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Vehicles"."Model", "Vehicles"."Color",
"Vehicles"."LicensePlate"
```

As an aside, it is considered good practice to use explicit joins (unless you're using a prehistoric version of oracle) instead of the `where` clause

```
FROM "WorkOrder" 
     inner join "Vehicles" on "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" 
     left join "WorkOrderPart" on "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID" = "WorkOrderPart"."WorkOrderID"
```

Comment: Yep and with other functions too like `SUM`, `MIN` or `MAX` - EDIT: Just seen your update :)

Comment: This does work, however, it seems I confused myself. My goal was to produce a row for each WorkOrderID in the WorkOrder table, and for the count to return 0 or more for the Parts COUNT. This only returns 1 row .

Comment: You probably want to change the `inner join` between workorder and workorderpart to a `left join` - see edit above